# Extract a string variable based on the middle of another string

Tags: python, string, extract

*UPDATE* I forgot that to specify that the variable with sentences is in fact an index.

I have an index in Python, `sent`, containing the following values from which I wish to extract/create a new string variable, `y`, that contains only the names in sent.

```
index                                                                        y
What you see in the picture is Alex eating his ice cream                     Alex
What you see in the picture is Claudia riding her new bike                   Claudia         
What you see in the picture is Alessandro painting a picture                 Alessandro
```

The number of letters on the LHS of the names in `sent`, `What you see in the picture is` is the same for all values, however, the RHS varies. Is it possible to get a solution that extracts from `df["y"]=df.sent.str[31:]` and until the following space?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find out.

Comment: Length of `"What you see in the picture is "` is 31, so you can use simple string slicing `s[31: s.find(" ", 31)]`

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the 8th word, right?

```
df['y'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['sent'].split()[7], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I obtain the following error when running the suggested code:  AttributeError: 'sent' object has no attribute 'split'``

Comment: Have you called split with parentheses? .split is seen as an attribute whereas split() is seen as a method.

Comment: df['y'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['sent'].split()[7], axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `"What you see in the picture is"` is the same for all values, you can split your string and keep the 8° item.

```
x= 'What you see in the picture is Alex eating his ice cream'

word = x.split()[7]
```